# C - Socket Echo Program

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to make a program that takes a string from the command line, that is passed in the command line arguments, sends it to the server, then sends it back to the client and displays it on the screen. Right now it is freezing on the server side, from what I can tell using print statements in the recvfrom() function. Does anyone know why it isn't echoing back? For the command line arguments, the server just takes the port number, and the client takes the server name, port number, and string to be echoed back. Below is my code:

Header file:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <signal.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

server.c:

```
#include "headerFiles.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int s;
    int len;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
    struct sockaddr_in clntAddr;
    int clntAddrLen;
    int serverPort;

    // Build local (server) socket address
    memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(serverPort);
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    // Create socket
    if((s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error: socket failed!");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Bind socket to local address and port
    if((bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0))
    {
        perror("Error: bind failed!");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(;;) // Runs forever
    {
        // Receive String
        printf("In infinite loop.\n");
        len = recvfrom(s, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clntAddr, &clntAddrLen);
        printf("Received something\n");

        // Send String
        sendto(s, buffer, len, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clntAddr, sizeof(clntAddr));
        printf("Sent something\n");
    }
}
```

client.c:

```
#include "headerFiles.h"

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) // Three arguments to be checked later
{
    int s; // Socket descriptor
    int len; // Length of string to be echoed
    char* servName; // Server name
    int servPort; // Server port
    char* string; // String to be echoed
    char buffer[256+1]; // Data buffer
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr; // Server socket address

    // Check and set program arguments
    if(argc != 4)
    {
        printf("Error: three arguments are needed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    servName = argv[1];
    servPort = atoi(argv[2]);
    string = argv[3];

    // Build server socket address
    memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, servName, &servAddr.sin_addr);
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(servPort);

    // Create socket
    if((s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error: Socket failed!");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Send echo string
    len = sendto(s, string, strlen(string), 0, &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));

    printf("Past sendto\n");

    // Receive echo string
    recvfrom(s, buffer, len, 0, NULL, NULL);

    //Print and verify echoed string
    buffer[len] = '\0';
    printf("Echo string received: ");
    fputs(buffer, stdout);
    printf("\n");

    // Close the socket
    close(s);

    // Stop the program
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: In server.c `serverPort` is uninitialized when passed to `htons`.

Comment: That worked! Can't believe I missed that... Thank you so much!

Comment: Though not directly causing your problem, also note that the `addrlen` (last paramater) passed to `recvfrom` is a  value-result parameter. That is, you need to set `clntAddrLen` to be `sizeof servAddr` before passing that to `recvfrom`.

Comment: If the `len` returned by `recv()` is zero you should close the socket and cease reading, and if it is -1 you should print the error, close the socket, and cease reading.